# Using a rolling average on coalesced values

Tags: sql, average, teradata, coalesce, rolling-computation

I'm unable to make a calculated column show an average.  Please see:

```
    Cast(AVG(COALESCE(mnth1.HandledCalls,0)+COALESCE(mnth2.HandledCalls,0)+COALESCE(mnth3.HandledCalls,0)) as Decimal(8,2))  as Avg_Handled,
```

How do I make this show an average of the 3 columns?  At times, mnth2 and mnth3 may not be populated.  I tried to divide by a count the coalesced months in case any are null at any given time.  I receive an error saying the select list is invalid.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the table structure to your question?

Comment: When calculation an AVG with one of the columns being NULL do you want the NULL treated as a ZERO, or do you want the average of just the other two columns?

Comment: The table structure is only selecting mnth1, mnth2, mnth 3 and the this average of the available values of each.  I'm using teradata 12.  And when null I want to treat as though it doesn't exist (aka the average of the other 2 columns)

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
cast(
    sum(
        coalesce(mnth1.HandledCalls, 0) +
        coalesce(mnth2.HandledCalls, 0) +
        coalesce(mnth3.HandledCalls, 0)
    )
as decimal(29, 10)) /
(
    count(mnth1.HandledCalls) +
    count(mnth2.HandledCalls) +
    count(mnth3.HandledCalls)
)
```

Comment: It seems so...simple...I will test when I'm back at my desk.  Thank you for replying.

Comment: Actually I don't know if it would work at Teradata, but you can try it

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
Cast(
     AVG((SELECT COALESCE(mnth1.HandledCalls,0) 
          UNION ALL SELECT COALESCE(mnth2.HandledCalls,0) 
          UNION ALL SELECT COALESCE(mnth3.HandledCalls,0) )) 
     AS  Decimal(8,2))  as Avg_Handled
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(ZEROIFNULL(mnth1.HandledCalls) 
     + ZEROIFNULL(mnth2.HandledCalls) 
     + ZEROIFNULL(mnth3.HandledCalls) as Decimal(8,2))  as Avg_Handled
FROM ....
```

By default NULL values are ignored by aggregate functions in Teradata.